# Keycloak clients ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS behind LB

Tags: jboss, keycloak

All local environment

- 1 keycloak 1.7 & 1.9 listening on port 8080
- 2 tomcat 7 with java webapp using Keycloak filter (not the adapter)
- 1 nginx load balancing the 2 tomcats. Nginx config below

  upstream smurfed {
          server localhost:8082;
          server localhost:8999;
      }

  ```
  server {
      listen 80;
              server_name localhost;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://smurfed/;
          proxy_redirect off;
                  proxy_set_header Host $host;
                      }
  ```

  }

My Keycloak client all defaults, 1 only valid redirect_uri. 
As soon as I validate the login in keycloak it gets crazy with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

The same thing happen in AWS having a ELB > tomcats or ELB > NGINX > tomcats.

Anyone had a similar issue ?

Comment: I just tried the Tomcat 7 adapter and it works OK. But that is a way less elegant solution since we have to drop jar files into the tomcat/lib directory

Comment: I got this suggestion in the keycloak mail list http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/server-installation.html#proxy-address-forwarding

Comment: [KIND OF RESOLVED] I was not able to make it work with the filter but following my previous document link it works perfectly with the tomcat adapter.

Comment: [RESOLVED] Looking at the source code of the filter I saw that is taking data from the httpSession instead looking at some config (token-store: cookie) like the adapter is doing.

So, I shared the sessions of tomcat in redis (nice tutorial here https://dzone.com/articles/load-balance-tomcat-nginx-and) and it worked with the Filter. I'll try to submit a patch for this.